periodicity of function $e^z$
I know that the function $e^z=e^xe^{\textbf i y}$ is periodic with period $2k\pi \textbf i$ also the function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ $(e^x\cos y,e^x\sin y)$ is periodic with period $y=2k\pi$  but when I try to solve the system
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
e^x \cos y=w_1 \\
e^x \sin y=w_2
\end{array}\right.
$$
then I have $x=\log \sqrt{w_1^2+w_2^2}$, $\tan y=\frac{w_2}{w_1}$ (and $y=\frac{\pi}{2}+k \pi$ if $w_1=0$ ) and now the solution became period not of period $2k\pi$ but $k\pi$.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

$\tan(y)=\frac{w_2}{w_1}$ is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

This might be instructive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

@JulioPuerta can you please write how should I  continue  in order to get the right solution ?

@Dsrksidemath It is clear that two solutions must have the same real part $x$. Dividing both sides by $e^x$ we get $\cos(y)=w_1/e^x$, $\sin(y)=w_2/e^x$. Now use that $\cos$ and $\sin$ have period $2\pi$.

@JulioPuerta  I have tried to sum the 2 espressione and get the equation $sin(y+\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{w_1}{e^x}+\frac{w_2}{e^x}$  but then I found an horrible solution that is $arcsin(\frac{w_1+w_2}{\sqrt2 \sqrt((w_1)^2+(w_2)^2)})-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi$ now I have the periodicit but this doesn t seems like the solution arg

@MartinR yes I think this is what I am looking for But how can I pass from Atan2 to $tany =\frac{w_2}{w_1}$ ?

@Dsrksidemath: I am not sure if I understand your question. You cannot determine $y$ using only its tangent. But $y = \operatorname{atan2}(w_2, w_1)$.

@MartinR No , no I mean $y=arctan(\frac{w_1}{w_2})+k\pi$ but in the defintion of  atan2 this $k\pi$ there isn't!   . So my problem is now what is relation between $k\pi$ to atan2? Sorr for this stupid question

The difficulty arises because some teachers of Complex Analysis teach the student to use the Atan2 function, mentioned in the comment of Martin R., to determine the angle associated with a complex number $~z = x + iy,~$ where $~x,y \in \Bbb{R},~$ and either $~x \neq 0,~$ or $~y \neq 0.~$
Sometimes, the math student does not understand the subtlety behind the Atan2 function, so the student wrongly assumes that the tangent function may be used instead.
For example, assume that $~z_1 = (3 + 4i),~$ and $~z_2 = (-3 - 4i).~$
Then, in an effort to express $~z_1~$ as $~re^{i\alpha},~$ and $~z_2~$ as $ ~se^{i\beta},~$ you would:

Compute $~\displaystyle r = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5.$

Compute $~\displaystyle \cos(\alpha) = \frac{3}{5}, ~\sin(\alpha) = \frac{4}{5}.~$ 
So, since $~\cos(\alpha)~$ and $~\sin(\alpha)~$ are both positive, you have that $~\alpha~$ is in the 1st quadrant. 
That is, $~0^\circ < \alpha < 90^\circ,~$ or (in radians) $~0 < \alpha < \pi/2.$

Compute $~\displaystyle s = \sqrt{(-3)^2 + (-4)^2} = 5.$

Compute $~\displaystyle \cos(\beta) = \frac{-3}{5}, ~\sin(\beta) = \frac{-4}{5}.~$ 
So, since $~\cos(\beta)~$ and $~\sin(\beta)~$ are both negative, you have that $~\beta~$ is in the 3rd quadrant. 
That is, $~180^\circ < \beta < 270^\circ,~$ or (in radians) $~\pi < \beta < 3\pi/2.$


So, you have that $~\alpha \neq \beta.$
At the same time, you have that
$$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)} = \frac{4/5}{3/5} = \frac{4}{3} = \frac{-4/5}{-3/5} = \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)} = \tan(\beta).$$

Suppose that $y = \bar{y} + 2 \pi n$
where $-\pi < \bar{y}\leq \pi$. This is the principal value of the the argument of $e^z$
Hence:
$$ \cos(y) = \cos(\bar{y}+2\pi n) = \cos(\bar{y})$$
$$ \sin(y) = \sin(\bar{y}+2\pi n) = \sin(\bar{y})$$
Therefore we can write:
$$ \tan(y) = \tan(\bar{y} + 2\pi n) = \tan(\bar{y})= \frac{w_1}{w_2} \tag{1}$$
with
$$\displaystyle \bar{y}= \operatorname{atan2\left(w_1,w_2\right)}  = \begin{cases}  \displaystyle \arctan\left(\frac{w_1}{w_{2}}\right) &\textrm{ if } w_2>0\\
\displaystyle \arctan\left(\frac{w_1}{w_2}\right) + \pi &\textrm{ if } w_1<0, w_2\geq 0\\
\displaystyle \arctan\left(\frac{w_1}{w_2}\right)-\pi &\textrm{ fi } w_2<0, w_1<0\\
\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2} &\textrm{ if } w_2 = 0, w_1>0\\
\displaystyle -\frac{\pi}{2} &\textrm{ if } w_2 = 0, w_1<0   \end{cases} \tag{2}$$.
Edit:
In your example, you are trying to solve the equation:
$$ \tan(y)  = \frac{w_1}{w_2}$$ or what  is the same from (1):
$$\boxed{ \frac{w_1}{w_2} = \tan(\bar{y})  \implies y = \operatorname{atan2}\left(\frac{w_1}{w_2}\right) +2\pi n  } $$

Note that our inversion is well defined given that Wikipedia says:

The function $\operatorname{atan2}$ computes the principal value of the argument function applied to the complex number $x +iy$. That is, $ \operatorname{atan2}(y,x) = \operatorname{Pr arg}(x+iy) = \operatorname{Arg}(x +y)$. The argument could be changed by an arbitrary multiple of $\mathbf{2π}$ (corresponding to a complete turn around the origin) without making any difference to the angle, but to define $\mathbf{\operatorname{atan2}}$ uniquely one uses the principal value in the interval $( -\pi, \pi ]$, that is, $\color{red}{−\pi < \operatorname{atan2}(y,x) \leq \pi}$.

So, the argument of $e^z$ is $2\pi$-periodic but we have to restrict the principal value of the argument to $(-\pi,\pi]$ to make the inversion.
Lets see a simple example:
suppose that $w_1=w_2=1$
Hence, from (1) and (2):
$$ 1 = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \tan\left(\underbrace{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{\bar{y}}+2\pi n\right) = \tan(y) \implies y = \frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi n $$
